# mysql - update table use regexp

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id FROM people WHERE id REGEXP 'id-(\d)*';
```

result

```
id-1
id-2
id-3
```

This above query works but when i run update query below, it don't affect any rows

```
UPDATE people SET id = REPLACE(id, 'id-(\d)*', 'id-4');
0 row(s) affected
```

Somebody can explain for me, what wrong ?

Comment: MySQL's regex engine does not do replacements or capture groups. It's purely for matching in a WHERE clause.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: You would be better off if you re-did the DB structure. This seems like madness.

Comment: @SomnathMuluk : i'm using Mysql

Comment: @tereško : it is only a example. i want to update the value in a field and it very good for me if i can use something like Regexp in mysql

Answer (score 1):

REPLACE() doesn't search for regular expressions. 
Try this. But regexp_replace() function is supported by some of the databases.

`This works for oracle, PostgreSQL`.
    `It doesn't work for MySQL`.

```
 UPDATE people  SET id  = regexp_replace(id ,'id-(\d)*' , 'id-4');
```

Comment: the question is tagged to mysql, why would you suggest something that is irrelevant ?

Comment: I specifically written test cases for different databases. You may see I have written comment in question section for asking database name. I thought this answer might help for thinking. Should I delete answer?

Comment: well, now the OP has tagged to mysql, then your answer is become irrelevant

Comment: @all : thanks for sharing , now i know about the regexp_replace with oracle and PostgreSQL. Do not need to delete your answer ^^!

Comment: @all This answer is definitively usefull, in the update can be processed offline user can unload / load into oracle or postgresql / unload / load back into mysql

Answer (score 0):

`REPLACE` does not use regular expressions, only vanilla strings. You're searching for the literal string `'id-(\d)*'`, not the `'id-'` followed by any number of digits. Presumably, you do not have such a weird string in your database.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE() does text replacement. There is no regular expression replacement in MySQL. Its better you perform REGEX with some server side scripting.

Comment: What i should use instead REPLACE in this case ?